# How to use Numeric[T] to represent zero of any numeric type

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, typeclass, zero

I have a piece of Scala code that I'd like to make more generic. I know that `Numeric[T]` exists, but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
  def sumMaps[A](m1: Map[A, Long], m2: Map[A, Long]): Map[A, Long] = {
    m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0L)) }
  }

  def sumMaps[A](m1: Map[A, Int], m2: Map[A, Int]): Map[A, Int] = {
    m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
  }

  def sumMaps[A](m1: Map[A, Double], m2: Map[A, Double]): Map[A, Double] = {
    m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
  }
```

I'd like to write something like this (just once), where the zero value gets auto-converted to a `B` type.

```
  def sumMaps[A, B: Numeric[?]](m1: Map[A, B], m2: Map[A, B]): Map[A, B] = {
    m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
def sumMaps[A, B](m1: Map[A, B], m2: Map[A, B])(implicit num: Numeric[B]): Map[A, B] = {
  m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> num.plus(v, m1.getOrElse(k, num.zero)) }
}
```

or

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
def sumMaps[A, B](m1: Map[A, B], m2: Map[A, B])(implicit num: Numeric[B]): Map[A, B] = {
  m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, num.zero)) }
}
```

or

```
def sumMaps[A, B: Numeric](m1: Map[A, B], m2: Map[A, B]): Map[A, B] = {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[B]]
  import num._
  m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + m1.getOrElse(k, zero)) }
}
```

The imports provide implicit conversion `infixNumericOps`

```
m1 ++ m2.map { case (k, v) => k -> (infixNumericOps(v) + m1.getOrElse(k, num.zero)) }
```

so we do not have to explicitly use `Numeric.plus` like in the first example.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is `import num._` style discouraged? I have seen this style often in macros, for example, `import c.universe._`.

Comment: No, that is perfectly fine, I was referring is that I do not see any value in using context bounds when one has to use `implicitly` to summon the implicit. But that is just a style preference of myself, thus I would just use an implicit parameter to have it named and call the import as you did.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I found a decent argument for not naming implicits on [slide 26](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/scala-3-by-example-better-semigroup-and-monoid-200106140918/95/scala-3-by-example-better-semigroup-and-monoid-26-638.jpg?cb=1578320042) of [Scala 3 by Example - better Semigroup and Monoid](https://www.slideshare.net/pjschwarz/scala-3-by-example-better-semigroup-and-monoid) by Philip Schwarz, where it is stated _"The point of givens or implicits is that the compiler will produce them for you, so why should you bother giving them a name?"_

Comment: Interesting. However, that slide refers more when creating the implicit rather than when using it, in which case, I agree that not having to name them on **Scala 3** will be great. Now, in the context of a method / function. I do think that if all **typeclasses** provide a summoner like `Monoid[T]` _(and apply in the companion)_ then it would a good argument for just use context bounds. But since many doesn't have such and the `implicitly` is too verbose for me, I prefer to just use plain implicit parameters.